# Scanner's .hasNextDouble() doesn't work properly

Tags: java

I have been struggling with getting this piece of code to work as planned. The if(answer.hasNextDouble()) is not executed properly. Here's the code:

```
//Variable for user input
String input = "";

//Creating a Scanner for keyboard
Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

//...and for user's input
Scanner answer = new Scanner(input);

//Variable for validity check
boolean loanTerm_check = false;

int loanTerm = 0;

while (loanTerm_check != true) {
    try {
        System.out.print("\nEnter loan term in months       : ");
        input = keyboard.nextLine();
        loanTerm = Integer.parseInt(input);

        //Negative or null term exception
        if (loanTerm <= 0) {
            System.out.println("It is impossible to calculate payments for " +
                    "negative, null and fractional terms. Press Enter to retry.");
            keyboard.nextLine();
            input = "";
        } else {
            loanTerm_check = true;
            input = "";
        }
    } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
        if (answer.hasNextDouble()) {
            System.out.println("It is impossible to calculate payments for " +
                    "negative, null and fractional terms. Press Enter to retry.");
        } else {
            System.out.println("You did not enter a valid loan term. " +
                    "You entered: " + input + ". Press Enter to retry.");
        }
        keyboard.nextLine();
        input = "";
        continue;
    }
}
```

And here's the sample run:

```
Enter loan term in months       : 45.6
You did not enter a valid loan term. You entered: 45.6. Press Enter to retry.
```

My idea was to check if the user entered a double value and print a specific error message prompting for retry.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that when you declare

```
Scanner answer = new Scanner(input);
```

it will use the string currently stored in `input` (which is the empty string). When you assign a new value to `input`, it does not update the text that `answer` is scanning. You want to use the string that the user entered, so you should move the declaration of `answer` into the `catch` clause.

Alternatively, you can try parsing `input` as a `double` (using `Double.parseDouble(input)`). If that throws an exception, then treat it the same as there not being a double, but if it succeeds, then `input` has something that parses as a double but not as an integer.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, I indeed thought that `input` had something into it...

Answer (score 1):

Problem is you are taking input from the user as a `String` and storing it in a `String` type variable `input` so ofcourse you don't have a `double`.

Change the data type of `input` variable to `double` and then take user input using

```
input = keyboard.nextDouble();
```

Answer (score 0):

You are getting NumberFormatException, since you are aren't passing parsable integer to [parseInt](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#parseInt(java.lang.String))

You need to change

```
loanTerm = Integer.parseInt(input);
```

to

```
loanTerm = Double.parseDouble(input);
```